# Objective C - Release using Core-Data

Tags: iphone, memory-management

Is this a right code from the point of view of memory management?

```
NSEntityDescription *description = [NSEntityDescription
                                        entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *eventRequest = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[eventRequest setEntity:description];
[description release];

NSPredicate *eventPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                                      @"(event == %@)", [item objectForKey:@"event"]];
[eventRequest setPredicate:eventPredicate];
```

Or i need to release description and eventPredicate?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at that code, the only object you own is the `eventRequest`. It is being autoreleased so you don't need to release it again.

From what I can see, based on naming convention, all the other objects aren't owned, so you don't need to release them.

The line `[description release];` will likely cause a crash for you somewhere down the line.

Comment: reading the next comment it says it's correct.. so i don't know what is the answer..

Comment: `description` shouldn't be release because it was not given to you from a method with the word "alloc", "copy", "retain" or "new" in it's name. Following the naming conventions for Cocoa, methods whose names do not contain those words shouldn't return an owning reference to an object (a retain count of +1). As far as you're concerned in this context your object has a retain count of 0 and you shouldn't release it.

Comment: please can you check this question because i don't know what is the correct answer? Thanks
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659020/iphone-where-allocate-memory-for-datasource

Answer (score -1):

You dont't need any releases for that code.  You should read [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) to find out why.