# Iphone: Where allocate memory for dataSource?

Tags: iphone, memory-management

i have an array used to populate the UITableView.

The question is where i should to allocate memory for it. I have two options in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear, but i don't know where is more efficient from the point of view of memory management.

Thanks

Edit:

I create the view doing the following:

```
NextViewController *nextController = [[ReservationsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NextViewController" bundle:nil];
nextController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];
[nextController release];
```

But i don't want to allocate memory every time is shown, only the first time the view is loaded in order to be right from the point of view of memory-management.

Comment: Where are allocating the array? Is it a property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want it to be allocated once then you should alloc it either in the init method or in awakeFromNib depending on how your view controller is created.

viewWillAppear will likely be called multiple times and viewDidLoad is not guaranteed to be called only once.

Comment: i edit my question. I don't want to leak memory if i allocate in viewwillAppear or viewDidLoad. So what is the right way?

Comment: Override the initWithNibName method and put it in there.

Answer (score 0):

If the array is a property just release it in the dealloc like so:

```
- (void)dealloc {
  [someArray release];
  [super dealloc];
}
```

If for some reason you switch to creating a local array in the viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear method make sure you release it as soon as your done with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you allocate memory in the [viewDidLoad](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLoad) method it will be done only when the view is loaded to memory. If you do this in the [viewWillAppear](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillAppear%3a) you will be doing this every time the view becomes visible.

Comment: but viewDidLoad is not guaranteed to be called only once, isn't it?

Comment: It depends on how you are managing your views. It will be called every time it's loaded to memory as the documentation says. If you have only one instance of the view in your app lifecycle and you push/pop this only instance, then it will be called only once.